# Allowed Special Character in Transformer

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to send xml file to server after processing it which has some special character like "佥佬佧佼A£".

Currently code looks like

```
 public class Utils {
 public static String transformToString(Document activeDocument) throws TransformerException{
 TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "true");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
    writer.toString();

}
```

Test class

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlPath);
         //Doing some process on doc and changing other values

         String xmlString = Utils.transformToString(doc);

         // Sending xml to soap
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(endpoint);
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(xmlString));
    post.setHeader(new BasicHeader("content-type", "text/xml"));
               .................
     } 
}
```

XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope ....>
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<Test>
    <Id>佥佬佧佼A£</Id>
    ..............
    ..........
</Test>
.........
```

I am getting xmlString  with Id value  :  ????A£
What I want is  : 佥佬佧佼A£

How can I do that ? I just want String format of that XML.

EDIT : I am loading one XML, Doing some changes into it, and sending that XML to SOAP, by Setting that document to httpPost.setEntity()

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: How are you viewing that output? You're calling `writer.toString()` but not doing anything with the result. It's hard to help with so little context - a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Edited question

Comment: That's still not a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Try to take everything else - e.g. SOAP - out of the system. Create a short but complete program which simply loads and XML document from a file, transforms it however you need to transform it, and writes it back to disk. Then you can look at that file with a normal text editor (one which supports the encoding you're using and the characters you're using).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
encoding="UTF-16"
```

instead of

```
encoding="UTF-8"
```